# tornado: AttributeError: 'StaticHandler' object has no attribute 'absolute_path'

Tags: python, html, css, server, tornado

I'm building a simple server with python tornado. Here is the code:

```
class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, param):
        print("\n\nthis is a get request from indexhandler:")
        if param:
            #print("frontend/" + param)
            self.render("frontend/" + param)
            print("I'm html")
        else:
            print("index.html")
            self.render("index.html")

class StaticHandler(tornado.web.StaticFileHandler):
    def initialize(self, path, default_filename=None):
        self.root = os.path.abspath(path) + os.path.sep
        self.default_filename = default_filename

    def head(self, path):
        self.get(path, include_body=False)

    def get(self, param, include_body=True):
        abspath = "frontend/" + param
        print(abspath)
        myfile = open(abspath, "rb")
        try:
            self.write(myfile.read())
        finally:
            myfile.close()

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
                (r"/(.*jpg$)", StaticHandler, {"path": "/frontend"}),
                (r"/(.*css$)", StaticHandler, {"path": "/frontend"}),
                (r"/(.*html$)", IndexHandler)
                ]

        super(Application, self).__init__(handlers, **settings)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(Application())
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

However, when I visit my website, all of img and css files get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1513, in _execute
        self.finish()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 973, in finish
        self.set_etag_header()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1416, in set_etag_header
        etag = self.compute_etag()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2436, in compute_etag
        version_hash = self._get_cached_version(self.absolute_path)
    AttributeError: 'StaticHandler' object has no attribute 'absolute_path'
[E 170502 11:44:48 web:2063] 500 GET /css/reset.css (108.61.177.156) 2.06ms
```

Comment: Says here to upgrade if you get that error: If you receive this message you should update the tornado package (from 2.1 to 3.2 package).

`$ sudo pip install --upgrade tornado`   https://github.com/eudicots/Cactus/issues/77

Comment: @JacobIRR   In fact I've read this issue and upgraded tornado but the error is still there. They might not the same problem. Because my error comes from `tornado/web.py` whereas the error in the issue77 comes from `server.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See the docs for StaticFileHandler, particularly "subclassing notes"](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.StaticFileHandler):

> Subclasses should only override methods discussed in this section; overriding other methods is error-prone. Overriding StaticFileHandler.get is particularly problematic due to the tight coupling with compute_etag and other methods.
>
> To change the way static urls are generated (e.g. to match the behavior of another server or CDN), override make_static_url, parse_url_path, get_cache_time, and/or get_version.

The problem here, in particular, is that `get` is supposed to set `self.absolute_path` ([see the code here](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/72e8695089833483c1352073679b4cffe3d47232/tornado/web.py#L2349)) but you've replaced that code with your own.

Instead of overriding `get`, I think you want to override `parse_url_path`:

```
def parse_url_path(self, url_path):
    return 'frontend/' + url_path
```